# How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-udf

I have a table with ~500k rows; varchar(255) UTF8 column `filename` contains a file name;

I'm trying to strip out various strange characters out of the filename - thought I'd use a character class: `[^a-zA-Z0-9()_ .\-]`

Now, **is there a function in MySQL that lets you replace through a regular expression**? I'm looking for a similar functionality to REPLACE() function - simplified example follows:

```
SELECT REPLACE('stackowerflow', 'ower', 'over');

Output: "stackoverflow"

/* does something like this exist? */
SELECT X_REG_REPLACE('Stackoverflow','/[A-Zf]/','-'); 

Output: "-tackover-low"
```

I know about [REGEXP/RLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943142/19746), but those only check *if* there is a match, not *what* the match is.

(I *could* do a "`SELECT pkey_id,filename FROM foo WHERE filename RLIKE '[^a-zA-Z0-9()_ .\-]'`" from a PHP script, do a `preg_replace` and then "`UPDATE foo ... WHERE pkey_id=...`", but that looks like a last-resort slow & ugly hack)

Comment: It's a feature request since 2007: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27389. If you really want this feature, log in and click "Affects me" button. Hopefully it will get enough votes.

Comment: @Tomas: I have done that...in 2009, when I was looking around for it. Since there has been zero progress on it - apparently it's not such an important feature. (btw Postgres has it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722995/regular-expression-find-and-replace-in-postgres )

Comment: Related, simpler, version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973/mysql-how-to-remove-all-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-a-string

Comment: I've created `regexp_split` (function + procedure) & `regexp_replace`, which are implemented with `REGEXP` operator. For simple lookups, it will do the trick. You may find it [here](https://github.com/almadomundo/mysql-regexp) - so, this is the way with MySQL stored code, no UDF. If you'll find some bugs, which are not covered by known limitations - feel free to open the issue.

Comment: IMO, selecting, using PHP, and then updating mysql is not such a bad "hack". I do prefer using MySQL native methods when possible - supposedly it's faster. But I have a system that uses a lot of PHP and it does hundreds of thousands of such replacements in a few seconds (the system I built is designed for exactly this kind of work).

Comment: Found this library from another SO thread: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg works perfectly.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

With *MySQL 8.0+* you could use natively `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.

[12.5.2 Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace):

> `REGEXP_REPLACE(expr, pat, repl[, pos[, occurrence[, match_type]]])`
>
> Replaces occurrences in the string **expr** that match the regular expression specified by the pattern **pat** with the replacement string **repl**, and returns the resulting string. If **expr**, **pat**, or **repl** is `NULL`, the return value is `NULL`.

and [Regular expression support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html):

> Previously, *MySQL* used the Henry Spencer regular expression library to support regular expression operators (`REGEXP`, `RLIKE`).
>
> Regular expression support has been reimplemented using International Components for Unicode (ICU), which provides full Unicode support and is multibyte safe. The `REGEXP_LIKE()` function performs regular expression matching in the manner of the `REGEXP` and `RLIKE` operators, which now are synonyms for that function. **In addition, the** `REGEXP_INSTR()`**,** `REGEXP_REPLACE()`**, and** `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` **functions are available to find match positions and perform substring substitution and extraction, respectively.**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Stackoverflow','[A-Zf]','-',1,0,'c'); 
-- Output:
-tackover-low
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2436ab953a61ed401284357140777d4)

Answer (score 192):

If you are using MariaDB or MySQL 8.0, they have a function

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, regexp, replace)
```

See [MariaDB docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/string-functions/regular-expressions-functions/pcre-regular-expressions/) and [PCRE Regular expression enhancements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/string-functions/regular-expressions-functions/pcre-regular-expressions/)

Note that you can use regexp grouping as well (I found that very useful):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("stackoverflow", "(stack)(over)(flow)", '\\2 - \\1 - \\3')
```

returns

```
over - stack - flow
```

Comment: this is from mariadb 10

Comment: Benni--thanks for pointing this out, but I'm a little confused on the actual implementation... mind chiming in on my question over here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498929/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-a-regex-find-and-replace-using-regexp-replace- cc @Piskvor

Comment: For the next time I need it, here's syntax for changing a whole column: `UPDATE table SET Name = REGEXP_REPLACE(Name, "-2$", "\\1")` This removes -2 from abcxyz-2 from a whole column at once.

Comment: Changing an entire platform is hardly a realistic solution.

Comment: @DavidBaucum MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL. So it is no "change of platform" but more like choosing a different airline for the same trip

Comment: @Benvorth [MySQL 8.0 supports it too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925597/5070879).

Comment: What if I want to replace a entire column at once and change s:[1-9] to s:5 for example? I think this is a bit confusing or maybe it's just me... this doesn't work `UPDATE table SET file_source = REGEXP_REPLACE("file_source", "s:[1-9]", "s:12");`

Comment: @Benvorth if you've already deployed to production, its more like choosing a different airline for the same trip _mid flight_

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("stackoverflow", "(stack)(over)(flow)", '$2 - $1 - $3')

For me, the above worked...

Answer (score 181):

## **MySQL 8.0+**:

You can use the native [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function.

## Older versions:

You can use a user-defined function (*UDF*)  like [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp).

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE as a User Defined Function? Looks promising, will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Mysql does not have that feature built-in. I'm told that Oracle has that (no help for you though)

Comment: Unfortunately mysql-udf-regexp doesn't seem to have support for multibyte characters. regexp_replace('äöõü', 'ä', '') returns a long numeric string instead of real text.

Comment: @lkraav Really? that thing sounds like a security leak since that "long numeric string" looks like some buffer overrun.

Comment: Well this was a year ago, but I'm pretty sure I identified the issue correctly at the time. No idea if they've made any progress, since I haven't touched this tool since.

Comment: MySQL itself does not support multi-byte characters with its RegEx features.

Comment: Windows users: The UDF Library linked here doesn't seem to have good windows support. The windows installation method outlined did not work well for me.

Comment: @lkraav you should try out the lib_mysqludf_preg library below as it works great.  This the verbose version as it returns a blob by default and I don't know if you have a multibyte charset as your default:
select cast( T.R as char)  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
 from 
(select preg_replace('/ä/', '', 'öõüä') R ) T

Comment: Does the native REGEXP_REPLACE function allow back-references?

Comment: Nice, thanks  --- I also got to a new realisation that UDFs are a real option.

Answer (score 122):

My brute force method to get this to work was just:

1. Dump the table - `mysqldump -u user -p database table > dump.sql`
2. Find and replace a couple patterns - `find /path/to/dump.sql -type f -exec sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g' {} \;`, There are obviously other perl regeular expressions you could perform on the file as well.
3. Import the table - `mysqlimport -u user -p database table < dump.sql`

If you want to make sure the string isn't elsewhere in your dataset, run a few regular expressions to make sure they all occur in a similar environment. It's also not that tough to create a backup before you run a replace, in case you accidentally destroy something that loses depth of information.

Comment: Okay, that should work, too; I didn't consider an offline replace. Nice out-of-the-box thinking there!

Comment: Seems strange to me that you'd use find like that, I would shorten the command to sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g' /path/to/dump.sql

Comment: Very risky, and unpractical with big data sets, or with referential integrity in place: for remove the data and then insert it again you will have to turn referential integrity off, leaving in practice your database off also.

Comment: Having used this method in the past, I aggre with Raul, this is very risky. You need to be absolutely certain as well, that your string is not elswhere in your dataset.

Comment: Years late to the answer @speshak but the reason I chose to access the file like this was because I originally very nervous for the same reasons as mentioned above. At the time it seemed like separating the "find the file" part from the "replace" part would make the code easier to read before I submitted it

Comment: One more confirmation: I enjoyed this method, until I started to get errors about the number of columns not maching the expected value ( = broken the whole db / table).

Comment: I the the lesson is to be very careful about your regular expression.

Answer (score 55):

I recently wrote a MySQL function to replace strings using regular expressions. You could find my post at the following location:

http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/

Here is the function code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Example execution:

```
mysql> select regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','','2my test3_text-to. check \\ my- sql (regular) ,expressions ._,');
```

Comment: I'll just reinforce the above point: this function replaces *characters* that match a single-character expression. It says above that it is used "to repalce strings using regular expressions", and that can be a little misleading. It does its job, but it's not the job being asked for. (Not a complaint - it is just to save leading people down the wrong path)

Comment: Nice – but unfortunately doesn't deal with references like `select regex_replace('.*(abc).*','\1','noabcde')` (returns 'noabcde', not 'abc').

Comment: I've modified this method to attempt to address some of the limitations mentioned above and more. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql#38660574).

Comment: @Izzy The builtin MySQL 8+ REGEXP_REPLACE function doesn't either, right? I'm trying and it does not seem to work

Comment: @golimar I have no idea. And I cannot test either, as I don't have MySQL 8 or higher.

Answer (score 49):

we solve this problem without using regex
this query replace only exact match string.

```
update employee set
employee_firstname = 
trim(REPLACE(concat(" ",employee_firstname," "),' jay ',' abc '))
```

Example:

> emp_id employee_firstname
>
> 1    jay
>
> 2    jay ajay
>
> 3    jay

After executing query result:

> emp_id  employee_firstname
>
> 1        abc
>
> 2        abc ajay
>
> 3        abc

Comment: @yellowmelon what are the two pairs of double quotes for?

Comment: He's padding the employeename with spaces before and after. This allows him to search-replace for (space)employeename(space), which avoids catching the employeename "jay" if its part of a larger string "ajay." Then he trims the spaces out when done.

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE 2:** A useful set of regex functions including [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) have now been provided in MySQL 8.0. This renders reading on unnecessary unless you're constrained to using an earlier version.

---

**UPDATE 1:** Have now made this into a blog post: http://stevettt.blogspot.co.uk/2018/02/a-mysql-regular-expression-replace.html

---

The following expands upon the [function provided by Rasika Godawatte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql#6216513) but trawls through all necessary substrings rather than just testing single characters:

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- USAGE
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- SELECT reg_replace(<subject>,
--                    <pattern>,
--                    <replacement>,
--                    <greedy>,
--                    <minMatchLen>,
--                    <maxMatchLen>);
-- where:
-- <subject> is the string to look in for doing the replacements
-- <pattern> is the regular expression to match against
-- <replacement> is the replacement string
-- <greedy> is TRUE for greedy matching or FALSE for non-greedy matching
-- <minMatchLen> specifies the minimum match length
-- <maxMatchLen> specifies the maximum match length
-- (minMatchLen and maxMatchLen are used to improve efficiency but are
--  optional and can be set to 0 or NULL if not known/required)
-- Example:
-- SELECT reg_replace(txt, '^[Tt][^ ]* ', 'a', TRUE, 2, 0) FROM tbl;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS reg_replace;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION reg_replace(subject VARCHAR(21845), pattern VARCHAR(21845),
  replacement VARCHAR(21845), greedy BOOLEAN, minMatchLen INT, maxMatchLen INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(21845) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN 
  DECLARE result, subStr, usePattern VARCHAR(21845); 
  DECLARE startPos, prevStartPos, startInc, len, lenInc INT;
  IF subject REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET result = '';
    -- Sanitize input parameter values
    SET minMatchLen = IF(minMatchLen IS NULL OR minMatchLen < 1, 1, minMatchLen);
    SET maxMatchLen = IF(maxMatchLen IS NULL OR maxMatchLen < 1
                         OR maxMatchLen > CHAR_LENGTH(subject),
                         CHAR_LENGTH(subject), maxMatchLen);
    -- Set the pattern to use to match an entire string rather than part of a string
    SET usePattern = IF (LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^', pattern, CONCAT('^', pattern));
    SET usePattern = IF (RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$', usePattern, CONCAT(usePattern, '$'));
    -- Set start position to 1 if pattern starts with ^ or doesn't end with $.
    IF LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^' OR RIGHT(pattern, 1) <> '$' THEN
      SET startPos = 1, startInc = 1;
    -- Otherwise (i.e. pattern ends with $ but doesn't start with ^): Set start pos
    -- to the min or max match length from the end (depending on "greedy" flag).
    ELSEIF greedy THEN
      SET startPos = CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - maxMatchLen + 1, startInc = 1;
    ELSE
      SET startPos = CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - minMatchLen + 1, startInc = -1;
    END IF;
    WHILE startPos >= 1 AND startPos <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
      AND startPos + minMatchLen - 1 <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
      AND !(LEFT(pattern, 1) = '^' AND startPos <> 1)
      AND !(RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$'
            AND startPos + maxMatchLen - 1 < CHAR_LENGTH(subject)) DO
      -- Set start length to maximum if matching greedily or pattern ends with $.
      -- Otherwise set starting length to the minimum match length.
      IF greedy OR RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$' THEN
        SET len = LEAST(CHAR_LENGTH(subject) - startPos + 1, maxMatchLen), lenInc = -1;
      ELSE
        SET len = minMatchLen, lenInc = 1;
      END IF;
      SET prevStartPos = startPos;
      lenLoop: WHILE len >= 1 AND len <= maxMatchLen
                 AND startPos + len - 1 <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject)
                 AND !(RIGHT(pattern, 1) = '$' 
                       AND startPos + len - 1 <> CHAR_LENGTH(subject)) DO
        SET subStr = SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, len);
        IF subStr REGEXP usePattern THEN
          SET result = IF(startInc = 1,
                          CONCAT(result, replacement), CONCAT(replacement, result));
          SET startPos = startPos + startInc * len;
          LEAVE lenLoop;
        END IF;
        SET len = len + lenInc;
      END WHILE;
      IF (startPos = prevStartPos) THEN
        SET result = IF(startInc = 1, CONCAT(result, SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, 1)),
                        CONCAT(SUBSTRING(subject, startPos, 1), result));
        SET startPos = startPos + startInc;
      END IF;
    END WHILE;
    IF startInc = 1 AND startPos <= CHAR_LENGTH(subject) THEN
      SET result = CONCAT(result, RIGHT(subject, CHAR_LENGTH(subject) + 1 - startPos));
    ELSEIF startInc = -1 AND startPos >= 1 THEN
      SET result = CONCAT(LEFT(subject, startPos), result);
    END IF;
  ELSE
    SET result = subject;
  END IF;
  RETURN result;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Demo**

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/EBC76181)

**Limitations**

1. This method is of course going to take a while when the subject
   string is large. ***Update:** Have now added minimum and maximum match length parameters for improved efficiency when these are known (zero = unknown/unlimited).*
2. It **won't** allow substitution of backreferences (e.g. `\1`, `\2`
   etc.) to replace capturing groups. If this functionality is needed, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541913/mysql-replace-html-links-of-given-domain#38661545) which attempts to provide a workaround by updating the function to allow a secondary find and replace within each found match (at the expense of increased complexity).
3. If `^`and/or `$` is used in the pattern, they must be at the very start and very end respectively - e.g. patterns such as `(^start|end$)` are not supported.
4. There is a "greedy" flag to specify whether the overall matching should be greedy or non-greedy. Combining greedy and lazy matching within a single regular expression (e.g. `a.*?b.*`) is not supported.

**Usage Examples**

The function has been used to answer the following StackOverflow questions:

- [How to count words in MySQL / regular expression
  replacer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408#38790017)
- [How to extract the nth word and count word occurrences in a MySQL
  string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507#50435373)
- [How to extract two consecutive digits from a text field in
  MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457#48808860)
- [How to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string in
  MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942973#38788657)
- [How to replace every other instance of a particular character in a MySQL
  string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478226#45555747)
- [How to get all distinct words of a specified minimum length from multiple columns in a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166445#56905363)

Comment: Unlike the documentation for this function suggests, `null` can't be used in place of 0 in `maxMatchLength` or `minMatchLength` arguments, at least in mariadb 5.5.60

Comment: Good spot - have now updated the SQL to allow `NULL`

Answer (score 17):

I'm happy to report that since this question was asked, now there is a satisfactory answer! Take a look at this terrific package:

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

Sample SQL:

```
SELECT PREG_REPLACE('/(.*?)(fox)/' , 'dog' , 'the quick brown fox' ) AS demo;
```

I found the package from [this blog post](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2011/12/installing-the-mysql-preg-plugin-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get/) as linked on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705437/is-there-a-mysql-equivalent-of-phps-preg-replace).

Answer (score 10):

You 'can' do it ... but it's not very wise ... this is about as daring as I'll try ... as far as full RegEx support your much better off using perl or the like.

```
UPDATE db.tbl
SET column = 
CASE 
WHEN column REGEXP '[[:<:]]WORD_TO_REPLACE[[:>:]]' 
THEN REPLACE(column,'WORD_TO_REPLACE','REPLACEMENT')
END 
WHERE column REGEXP '[[:<:]]WORD_TO_REPLACE[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: No, that won't work.  Imagine your column contains 'asdfWORD_TO_REPLACE WORD_TO_REPLACE".  Your method would result in 'asdfREPLACEMENT REPLACEMENT" where the correct answer would be "asdfWORD_TO_REPLACE REPLACEMENT".

Comment: @Ryan ... that's exactly why I stated that it wasn't very wise ... in the use case you provide this would most definitely fail. In short it's a bad idea to use 'regex-like' structure. Even worse ... if you drop the where clause all your values will be NULL ...

Comment: Actually Ryan in this case you're incorrect as the markers will only find matches for the zero-length word 'boundaries' so only words with boundaries before and after the word would match ... It's still a bad idea though ...

Answer (score 9):

I think there is an easy way to achieve this and It's working fine for me.

**To SELECT rows using REGEX**

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name_to_find` REGEXP 'string-to-find'
```

**To UPDATE rows using REGEX**

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET column_name_to_find=REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name_to_find, 'string-to-find', 'string-to-replace') WHERE column_name_to_find REGEXP 'string-to-find'
```

REGEXP Reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/

Comment: Thank you :) It is possible to do easily since version 8.

Answer (score 6):

We can use IF condition in SELECT query as below:

Suppose that for anything with "ABC","ABC1","ABC2","ABC3",..., we want to replace with "ABC" then using REGEXP and IF() condition in the SELECT query, we can achieve this.

Syntax:

```
SELECT IF(column_name REGEXP 'ABC[0-9]$','ABC',column_name)
FROM table1 
WHERE column_name LIKE 'ABC%';
```

Example:

```
SELECT IF('ABC1' REGEXP 'ABC[0-9]$','ABC','ABC1');
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I have been trying something similar, but the performance on my data sets has been unsatisfactory. For smallish sets, this may be viable.

Answer (score 4):

The one below basically finds the first match from the left and then replaces all occurences of it (tested in [mysql-5.6](/questions/tagged/mysql-5.6)).

***Usage:***

```
SELECT REGEX_REPLACE('dis ambiguity', 'dis[[:space:]]*ambiguity', 'disambiguity');
```

***Implementation:***

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION REGEX_REPLACE(
  var_original VARCHAR(1000),
  var_pattern VARCHAR(1000),
  var_replacement VARCHAR(1000)
  ) RETURNS
    VARCHAR(1000)
  COMMENT 'Based on https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/'
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_replaced VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT var_original;
  DECLARE var_leftmost_match VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT
    REGEX_CAPTURE_LEFTMOST(var_original, var_pattern);
    WHILE var_leftmost_match IS NOT NULL DO
      IF var_replacement <> var_leftmost_match THEN
        SET var_replaced = REPLACE(var_replaced, var_leftmost_match, var_replacement);
        SET var_leftmost_match = REGEX_CAPTURE_LEFTMOST(var_replaced, var_pattern);
        ELSE
          SET var_leftmost_match = NULL;
        END IF;
      END WHILE;
  RETURN var_replaced;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION REGEX_CAPTURE_LEFTMOST(
  var_original VARCHAR(1000),
  var_pattern VARCHAR(1000)
  ) RETURNS
    VARCHAR(1000)
  COMMENT '
  Captures the leftmost substring that matches the [var_pattern]
  IN [var_original], OR NULL if no match.
  '
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_temp_l VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE var_temp_r VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE var_left_trim_index INT;
  DECLARE var_right_trim_index INT;
  SET var_left_trim_index = 1;
  SET var_right_trim_index = 1;
  SET var_temp_l = '';
  SET var_temp_r = '';
  WHILE (CHAR_LENGTH(var_original) >= var_left_trim_index) DO
    SET var_temp_l = LEFT(var_original, var_left_trim_index);
    IF var_temp_l REGEXP var_pattern THEN
      WHILE (CHAR_LENGTH(var_temp_l) >= var_right_trim_index) DO
        SET var_temp_r = RIGHT(var_temp_l, var_right_trim_index);
        IF var_temp_r REGEXP var_pattern THEN
          RETURN var_temp_r;
          END IF;
        SET var_right_trim_index = var_right_trim_index + 1;
        END WHILE;
      END IF;
    SET var_left_trim_index = var_left_trim_index + 1;
    END WHILE;
  RETURN NULL;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
UPDATE table_name 
  SET column_name = 'seach_str_name'
  WHERE column_name REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9()_ .\-]';
```